# Retrieving multiples values from a unsigned char in C

Tags: c, sockets, unsigned

I have write in a unsigned char *, two int and send it via a socket in C.
How can i retrieve those values from the receiver side.

Code:

```
unsigned char * request = malloc (8 * sizeof(unsigned char));

int index = htonl(rand() % 1000);
int size =  htonl(key_size);

memcpy(request, &ind,4);
memcpy(request+4, &size,4);
```

Comment: What is `ind`?   You should probably fix any typos and post accurate code.

Comment: You seem to be assuming `sizeof(int) == 4`.  Don't make that assumption.

Comment: You can assume `sizeof(unsigned char) == 1`, though.  You should be doing `unsigned char * requests = malloc(2 * sizeof(int))`. When you write magic numbers like `8`, it's not clear to the reader if you mean `CHAR_BIT` or `Days_in_week + 1` or something else entirely.  I suspect that you mean `2 * sizeof(int)`, but it would be better if the code were explicit about it.

Comment: Use a strict protocol and define corresponding structs, instead of sending some arbitrary sized values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just reverse all those operations. Read from the socket into `buffer`, then use:

```
int index, size;

memcpy(&index, buffer, 4);
memcpy(&size, buffer+4, 4);

index = ntohl(index);
size = ntohl(size);
```

Note that all your code assumes that `sizeof int == 4`. It would be better to use `int32_t` to ensure that the variables are the expected size.